# "Local" git repo in redmine - openshift

Tags: git, openshift, redmine

I have redmine installed on openshift, and I want to make a GIT repo on it.

Is it possible? What location must I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every OpenShift application you create has its own Git repository that only you can access

This is like normal git, how you work on github

open shift client tool called rhc setup install .. and confiqure

> rhc

will automatically download a copy of that repository to your local system.

> git add .openshift
>   $ git commit -m "Adding a build hook"
>   $ git push

Comment: Because question is create another repo from OpenShift application.